# Bind object with Model in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I wanna bind list variable with Model Object which i am used in JSP page. but i can't find Model value on JSP page. it's return only null.but if i am print this object using `System.out.println(s)` they will print perfect value but i am unable to find this object value on JSP page. what are the possible reason behind that ?

```
${list}                             //nothing to print on jsp page
<%=session.getAttribute("list")%>   //this will return null on jsp
```

My controller code is here:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/orderList/detailview/{orderId}")
public String viewDetails(@PathVariable("orderId") Integer orderId,HttpSession session, Model m) {

    List<OrderFullViewDTO> s=orderService.fullViewDetails(orderId);
    System.out.println("-----output is------"+s);
    m.addAttribute("list", s);
    session.setAttribute("list", s);

    return "redirect:/admin/orderList";
}


        @RequestMapping("/admin/orderList") public String orderList(Model m) { 
//Show all order placed by the user 
    m.addAttribute("op", orderDao.findAll()); 
    m.addAttribute("notify", notifyDao.totalListRecords());    m.addAttribute("notifyOrder", notifyDao.totalOrderRecord()); 
    return "OrderList"; 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are setting it in session as well as Model?

Comment: he might be testing either of one should work

Comment: i just want a list value in jsp page. do you have any another idea to do that ?

Comment: never use same reference name for two objects either same or different.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to some url, so browser performs a new GET request and load the page, You should use flash attributes concept to hold the parameters;

[REFER](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/orderList/detailview/{orderId}")
public String viewDetails(@PathVariable("orderId") Integer orderId,HttpSession session, Model m, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

    List<OrderFullViewDTO> s=orderService.fullViewDetails(orderId);
    System.out.println("-----output is------"+s);
 redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("list", s);
    return "redirect:/admin/orderList";
}
```

In JSP you can access same as model attributes.

**UPDATE**

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/orderList") public String orderList(Model m, @RequestParam List<OrderFullViewDTO> list) { 
//Show all order placed by the user 
    m.addAttribute("op", orderDao.findAll()); 
    m.addAttribute("notify", notifyDao.totalListRecords());    m.addAttribute("notifyOrder", notifyDao.totalOrderRecord()); 
m.addAttribute("list", list);
    return "OrderList";
```

Comment: can you post the method which you are redirecting to?

Comment: `HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 's' is not present`

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/orderList")
public String orderList(Model m) {
    //Show all order placed by the user
    m.addAttribute("op", orderDao.findAll());
    m.addAttribute("notify", notifyDao.totalListRecords());
    m.addAttribute("notifyOrder", notifyDao.totalOrderRecord());
    return "OrderList";
}
```

Comment: You provide the answer for second method but in first you made mistake by making two object with same name.